# \RaggedLeft in a \newcommand not working as expected

Tags: horizontal-alignment, ragged2e

I want to have two lines (some kind of "page metadata") on every subsection right-aligned. Those lines are *never* going to be full width (one contains a date only).

For that I was trying to define a command which places them into a RaggedLeft environment to (1) avoid all those "Underfull hbox" warnings and (2) not to type that much.

It just does not work.

```latex
% !TEX root = ./raggedleft.tex

\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[english,ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage{lmodern,textcomp}
\usepackage{ifluatex}
\ifluatex
  \usepackage{luacode}
  \usepackage{fourier}
  \usepackage{fontspec}
  \setmainfont{Erewhon}
\else
  \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
  \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
  \usepackage{fourier}
\fi
\usepackage[document]{ragged2e}

\setlength{\parskip}{1em}
\setlength{\parindent}{3em}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.2}

%% new command: \postheader{datestring}{tagstring}
%% prints the post date and tags right-aligned
\newcommand\postheader[2]{%
  \begin{RaggedLeft}%
  #1\\#2%
  \end{RaggedLeft}%
}


\begin{document}

\postheader{Some weird words on the right}{and more words, hopefully right-bound}

Normal boring left-aligned text.

\end{document}
```

The result is that the 2nd line is left-bound, and I still get an "underfull hbox" warning.

Fun fact: If I place this in a `\FlushRight` environment it works, but this is (1) not what I want, (2) I still get the warnings, and (3) I don't understand it at all, and I don't like things I don't understand ;) .

Experiments with non-ragged2e commands yield the same results.

I'm using latexmk (with luatex 1.10.0 / TeX live 2019) on Mac.

Comment: Add `\par` instead of `%` before `\end{RaggedLeft}`.

Comment: Why not `\hfill#1\\\hfill#2`? No `underfull` with that.

Comment: I went for @egreg's solution - least amount of typing ;)

Comment: thanks @Sigur for your solution, I'll keep that in mind - I did not know about hfill.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What happens is that `\end{RaggedLeft}` simply ends the flush right typesetting, but issues no paragraph ending command, so the second line is typeset with the standard settings.

In your case `\RaggedLeft` is not the right tool, because with short lines you'd get underfull boxes. Use the standard `\raggedleft` declaration.

I minimized the example, by removing all inessential bits.

```
\documentclass{article}

%% new command: \postheader{datestring}{tagstring}
%% prints the post date and tags right-aligned
\newcommand\postheader[2]{%
  \par\begingroup\raggedleft #1\\#2\\\endgroup
}


\begin{document}

\postheader{Some weird words on the right}{and more words, hopefully right-bound}

Normal boring left-aligned text.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This actually works as well :) . Thanks!